# ImportError when setting wagtail development environment : "cannot import name 'Query' from 'wagtail.search.models'"

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm currently working on a fork of Wagtail (version 6.0a0) and attempting to set up a development environment for contributing to the project. I've followed the standard steps for setting up the project but have encountered an ImportError when running migrations for a Wagtail-based website.

**Steps I've Taken:**

- Cloned the forked repository locally.
- Activated a Python virtual environment for my work.
- Installed the cloned project using "pip install -e .[testing,docs] -U."
- Executed "npm ci" and "npm run build" for JavaScript dependencies.
- Created a new Wagtail website in a separate directory.
- Ran "python manage.py migrate," and encountered the ImportError.

**Error Message:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "path/to/manage.py", line 10, in 
        ...
        from wagtail.search.models import Query
ImportError: cannot import name 'Query' from 'wagtail.search.models'

**Additional Information:**

- The released version of Wagtail (version 5.2a0) installs successfully using "pip install wagtail" without any issues.
- My requirements file specifies Django version 4.2, but Django version 4.0.10 is installed in my Python virtual environment.(this version was installed with the cloned wagtail project)
- The requirements.txt file in the website generated by Wagtail specifies the following: Django>=4.2,<4.3 // wagtail==5.2a0

I at first thought this might be a dependency versions problem because the released version works fine with the Django 4.2 version, so I updated Django to 4.2 but the issue remained.

**My questions:**

- What could be causing this ImportError when using my fork of Wagtail (version 6.0a0) that doesn't occur when using the released version (5.2a0)?
- How to set the development environment to contribute to wagtail (I tried following the docs as shown but i cant set it right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in Rich's answer, the Query model (referenced in `search/views.py` in
the initial project structure created by `wagtail start`) was moved from the `wagtail.search` module to `wagtail.contrib.search_promotions` in Wagtail 5.0. The old model was left in place until work began on Wagtail 6.0 a week or two ago.

Leaving the original import in place in the default project structure was a mistake, and I've now submitted a fix for this: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/11190. Once this is fix is merged, bringing up a new project will work as intended.

In the meantime, you can patch the created project yourself - either change the import in `search/views.py` as Rich suggests, or remove it along with these two lines in the `search` function:

```
    query = Query.get(search_query)
    query.add_hit()
```

Alternatively, I'd recommend using [bakerydemo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/) as a test project for developing Wagtail against, rather than creating a new project from scratch - the relevant fix was applied to bakerydemo a while back.

Answer (score 1):

There's a deprecation warning regarding search:

> RemovedInWagtail60Warning: The wagtailsearch.Query model has been
> moved to  wagtail.contrib.search_promotions. Please update your code
> to use the Query model from that app instead.

And note in the 5.0 release notes:
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/5.0.html#wagtailsearch-query-migration

Amend your import path to

```
from wagtail.contrib.search_promotions.models import Query
```

It generates a migration file after changing to this model

You also have to add `wagtail.contrib.search_promotions` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.

Comment: Note that if you follow this route, you'll also have to add `wagtail.contrib.search_promotions` to the INSTALLED_APPS list.